# Using tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer with multiple optimizers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to run the DeepLab Resnet (https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet) in a distributed setup. I opted Synchronous Data parallel training approach similar to the one demonstrated in Inception's distributed training example.(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception).

In the example, tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer is used to aggregate gradients from every worker which use a single RMSPropOptimizer. The global_step variable is also updated by the function. Following snippet depicts this typical case:

```
# Optimizer in every worker that performs gradient descent. 
opt=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr,RMSPROP_DECAY,
momentum=RMSPROP_MOMENTUM, 
epsilon=RMSPROP_EPSILON)

# A synchronous replica optimizer that wraps the RMSoptimizer
  opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(opt,
      replicas_to_aggregate=num_replicas_to_aggregate,
      total_num_replicas=num_workers,
      variable_averages=exp_moving_averager,
      variables_to_average=variables_to_average)

#Apply gradients and update global_step
apply_gradients_op =opt.apply_gradients(grads,global_step=global_step)
```

In my case,three optimizers with different learning rates each meant for a specific portion of the network are used.

```
#Three optimizers declared with different learning rates
opt_conv = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, args.momentum)
opt_fc_w = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate * 10.0, args.momentum)
opt_fc_b = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate * 20.0, args.momentum)

#Scope for every optimizer 
grads = tf.gradients(reduced_loss, conv_trainable + fc_w_trainable + fc_b_trainable)
grads_conv = grads[:len(conv_trainable)]
grads_fc_w = grads[len(conv_trainable) : (len(conv_trainable) + len(fc_w_trainable))]
grads_fc_b = grads[(len(conv_trainable) + len(fc_w_trainable)):]

#Gradients applied to various portions of the network
train_op_conv = opt_conv.apply_gradients(zip(grads_conv, conv_trainable))
train_op_fc_w = opt_fc_w.apply_gradients(zip(grads_fc_w, fc_w_trainable))
train_op_fc_b = opt_fc_b.apply_gradients(zip(grads_fc_b, fc_b_trainable)) 

#train_op groups all optimizer operations
train_op = tf.group(train_op_conv, train_op_fc_w, train_op_fc_b)
```

I don't have any clue about using the tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer for  multiple optimizers. Also, I don't have an idea about updating the global_step variable and using the chief_queue_runner for this case. Please help me on this.